# Verifying permissions on OSX

Tags: macos, xorg, xcode, disk-utility, verification

Last week i was having trouble installing homebrew onto a new mac running mountain lion, i tried adding command line tools for xcode and installing X11 aswell as following a load of other things i found online.. all this got me no were and to the point were i didnt know what id done. So i decided seeing as it was a new machine to wipe the HD and do a clean install of mountain lion.

Now that ive done that if i go to disk utility to verify the disk premissions i get a load of xcode and X11 related errors, i run permission repair, but it never seems to fix them.. any ideas what i can do ? Is it best to do another clean install ? (how clean is a clean install as im not sure why its getting these X11 errors as i didnt install it again after i did the first wipe..)

heres the log from disk utility (bellow) note i can run verify, then repair, then verify again and the same problems come up ?

```
Verifying permissions for “Macintosh HD”
Permissions differ on “usr/X11/bin/freetype-config”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/agvtool”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/ibtool”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/instruments”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/opendiff”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/xcode-select”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/xcodebuild”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .

Permissions verification complete

Repairing permissions for “Macintosh HD”
Permissions differ on “usr/X11/bin/freetype-config”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired “usr/X11/bin/freetype-config”
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/agvtool”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired “usr/bin/agvtool”
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/ibtool”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired “usr/bin/ibtool”
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/instruments”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired “usr/bin/instruments”
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/opendiff”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired “usr/bin/opendiff”
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/xcode-select”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired “usr/bin/xcode-select”
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/xcodebuild”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired “usr/bin/xcodebuild”

Permissions repair complete

Verifying permissions for “Macintosh HD”
Permissions differ on “usr/X11/bin/freetype-config”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/agvtool”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/ibtool”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/instruments”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/opendiff”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/xcode-select”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on “usr/bin/xcodebuild”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .

Permissions verification complete
```

Comment: If you know a better title for this question please suggest it as an edit ..

Comment: Have you tried repairing the disk from the [recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718)?

Comment: @LauriRanta i havnt, when i reinstalled the system i did it via the internet recovery, is it different via the partition ?

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't actually permissions errors -- if you look at the detailed errors, like `Permissions differ on “usr/bin/xcodebuild”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xr-x .`, the difference is in the first symbol (`l` vs. `-`), which is the item type, not a permissions flag.  The "should be" type, `l`, indicates a symbolic link, while `-` indicates a plain file. On my computer:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/xcodebuild
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  5 Jul 13 16:35 /usr/bin/xcodebuild -> xcrun
```

I haven't updated Xcode in a while, so it's possible it *should* be a plain file in the latest version; or it may be that your install of Xcode is somehow garbled. In either case, the permissions themselves are fine. If there is a problem, it's something ... different.